# Label intValue not show for greater than (>) to work

Tags: swift

I am new at Swift the code builds just fine but the greater than (>) dose not work.  I'm trying to producing at a number in the "totalCoal" label, but never goes over the "coalPileHolding" Second label. I know that this code can be way better But i am trying to get the basic first.   I also know that the timeDiffernt ">" dose not work also so somehow I am missing something.  Thank you for your help

```
 @IBOutlet weak var coalPileHoldingLabel: UILabel!
func loadBigCoalPile () {
    var coalPileHolding = Int ()
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "coalPileResearch") == nil {
        coalPileHolding = 0 } else {
        coalPileHolding = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "coalPileResearch") as! Int}
    if coalPileHolding == 1 {
        let coalPileHolding = 200
        coalPileHoldingLabel.text = String(coalPileHolding) }
    if coalPileHolding == 2 {
        let coalPileHolding = 300
        coalPileHoldingLabel.text = String(coalPileHolding) }
    if coalPileHolding == 3 {
        let coalPileHolding = 400
        coalPileHoldingLabel.text = String(coalPileHolding) }

@objc func buttonIsInAction(){

}
@IBOutlet weak var coalRunButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func coalRunButton(_ sender: Any) {

    func getMillisecondsNow() -> Int64{
        let currentDate = Date()
        return getMillisecondsFromDate(date: currentDate)
    }
    func getMillisecondsFromDate(date: Date) -> Int64{
        var d : Int64 = 0
        let interval = date.timeIntervalSince1970
        d = Int64(interval * 1000)
        return d
    }
    func getTimeDifferenceFromNowInMilliseconds(time: Int64) -> Int64{
        let now = getMillisecondsNow()
        let diff: Int64 = now - time
        return diff
    }
    var terminationTime = Int64()
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") == nil {
        terminationTime = getMillisecondsNow()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(terminationTime, forKey:"latestTerminationDate")
        }
    else {

     terminationTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "latestTerminationDate") as! Int64 }

   let timeDiff = getTimeDifferenceFromNowInMilliseconds(time: terminationTime)
    let timeDiffernt = Int(timeDiff)
    let now = getMillisecondsNow()
    UserDefaults.standard.set (now, forKey: "latestTerminationDate")
    if  timeDiffernt > 86400000 { _ = 86400000}

    var methodOfCut = Int ()
    var machineryButton = Int ()
    var qualityOfWorkers = Int ()
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "methodOfCut") == nil {
        methodOfCut = 0 } else {
        methodOfCut = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "methodOfCut") as! Int}
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "machineryButton") == nil {
        machineryButton = 0 } else {
        machineryButton = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "machineryButton") as! Int}
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "qualityOfWorkers") == nil {
        qualityOfWorkers = 0 } else {
        qualityOfWorkers = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "qualityOfWorkers") as! Int}

    let coalMayham = (machineryButton) + (qualityOfWorkers) + (methodOfCut)
    let (dailyCoalAccumulate) = ((timeDiffernt) * (coalMayham) + 1) / 10000

    var coalPileHolding2 = 0
    if let coalPile = Int(coalPileLabel.text!) {
    let totalCoal = (dailyCoalAccumulate) + coalPile
         coalPileHolding2 = Int(coalPileHoldingLabel.text!) ?? 0
    if totalCoal > coalPileHolding2 { coalPileHolding2 = totalCoal }

        coalPileLabel.text = String(totalCoal)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(totalCoal, forKey:"totalCoal")}
        callOutLabel.text = String(dailyCoalAccumulate)}}
```

Comment: Your mix of different numeric types is rather weird. What kind of numbers are you expecting in your text fields?

Comment: @Sven I hope you think good weird? coalPile is the production based on time.  coalPileHolding is the research much like a silo of how much coal it can hold

Comment: What I meant is do you expect whole numbers (integers like 1, 2, 3 and so on) or also fractional numbers (like 1.5, 3.6 4.99 and so on)

Comment: @Sven I like the change back to Int

Comment: @Sven i did what you said but the update code does the same thing no errors builds fine but totalCoal exceeds over coal pile holding.

Comment: Post some more code, and explain exactly what behavior you see and what you are expecting. With the information you provide here I can’t do any better.

Comment: @Sven I update the question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

That mix of numeric types (Int32, Float, Int) is rather confusing. In general you want to use Int or Double. All other variants should only be used when absolutely necessary, for example if an API requires a different type. So lets assume that `dailyCoalAccumulate` is Int and switch everything else to Int too:

```
let coalPileHolding = 0 
if let coalPile = Int(coalPileLabel.text!) {
    let totalCoal = dailyCoalAccumulate + coalPile
    let coalPileHolding = Int((coalPileHoldingLabel.text as! NSString).intValue)
    if totalCoal > coalPileHolding {
        let coalPileHolding = totalCoal
    }
    coalPileLabel.text = String(totalCoal)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(totalCoal, forKey:"totalCoal") 
} 
callOutLabel.text = String(dailyCoalAccumulate)
```

Here the `intValue` API of `NSString` returns `Int32` but I immediately convert it to a regular Int. But of course there is a better way to do this without having to bridge to the Objective-C `NSString`. If the string doesn't contain a number `intValue` simply returns zero. We can produce the same behavior when we use the Int initializer to convert the string and then replace the `nil` value with zero: `Int(coalPileHoldingLabel.text!) ?? 0`.

Then we have three different variables named `coalPileHolding`. Since they are defined in different scopes they can share the same name, but are still different variables. My guess is that you want to actually update the `coalPileHolding` variable. Otherwise the assignment in the inner if makes no sense - the compiler even warns about that.

So lets change `coalPileHolding` to `var` and update its value.

```
var coalPileHolding = 0 
if let coalPile = Int(coalPileLabel.text!) {
    let totalCoal = dailyCoalAccumulate + coalPile
    coalPileHolding = Int(coalPileHoldingLabel.text!) ?? 0
    if totalCoal > coalPileHolding {
        coalPileHolding = totalCoal
    }
    coalPileLabel.text = String(totalCoal)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(totalCoal, forKey:"totalCoal") 
} 
callOutLabel.text = String(dailyCoalAccumulate)
```